# Calling WCF service in Jquery throwing errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, sql-insert

I want to insert data into sql server calling WCF in Jquery. I dont know why I am getting an error which is very dificult to trace out. I am giving the code below Please help  .

1) IService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);
}

[DataContract]
public class UserDetails
{

    string empname = string.Empty;
    string empdesignation = string.Empty;

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName
    {
        get { return empname; }
        set { empname = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpDesignation
    {
        get { return empdesignation; }
        set { empdesignation = value; }
    }
```

---

2) Service1.svc.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{


    public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)

    {

        string Message;


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=abc123");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_emp(EmpName,EmpDesignation) values(@EmpName,@EmpDesignation)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", userInfo.EmpName);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpDesignation", userInfo.EmpDesignation);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result == 1)

        {

            Message = userInfo.EmpName + " Details inserted successfully";

        }

        else

        {

         Message = userInfo.EmpName + " Details not inserted successfully";

        }

        con.Close();
        return Message;

    }
}
```

---

3)Service1.svc Markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MobileService.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

---

4) Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>

      <service name="MobileService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding ="webHttpBinding" contract="MobileService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior"></endpoint>
        <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

---

5) webform.aspx

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Call WCF Service using jQuery JSON AJax Sample in Asp.net</title>
<%--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {

        $(function () {
            $('#tbDetails').hide();
            $('#btnClick').click(function () {
                var empdata = {
                    "Empnames": "hai",
                    "empdesg": "hello"

                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'http://localhost:44060/Service1.svc/InsertUserDetails',
                    //data: '{"Username": "' + $("#txtName").val() + '"}',
                    //data: '{"Empnames":'" + $("#txtName").val() + "', "empdesg":'" + $("#txtDesg").val() + "'}',
                    //data:JSON.stringify(empdata),
                    data: '{ "Empnames": "' + $("#txtName").val() + '", "empdesg": "' + $("#txtDesg").val() + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success")
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('Exeption:' + xhr.status + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });

            });
        });

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);

    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<b>Enter UserName:</b> <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <b>Enter Designation:</b> <input type="text" id="txtDesg" />
<input type ="button" id="btnClick" value="Get Data" />
<table id="tbDetails" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead style="background-color:#DC5807; color:White; font-weight:bold">
<tr style="border:solid 1px #000000">
<td>UserId</td>
<td>UserName</td>
<td>Role</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I am getting error like this:

Sort by key

ExceptionDetail

```
Object { Message="Object reference not set... instance of an object.",  StackTrace="   at MobileService.Serv... isOperationContextSet)",  Type="System.NullReferenceException",  more...}
```

HelpLink `null`

InnerException  `null`

Message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

StackTrace

```
at MobileService.Service1.InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo) in c:\Users\Apple\Downloads\MobileService (2)\MobileService\MobileService\Service1.svc.cs:line 42
at SyncInvokeInsertUserDetails(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out the Line 42 of `Service1.svc.cs` is quite difficult.

However, it seems to be here:

```
if (result == 1)
{
    Message = userInfo.EmpName + " Details inserted successfully";
}
else
{
    Message = userInfo.EmpName + " Details not inserted successfully";
}
```

userInfo Object appears to be null. You might add some code around this to check the nullability of userInfo before trying to get EmpName.

Since your code in your aspx is :

```
data: '{ "Empnames": "' + $("#txtName").val() + '", "empdesg": "' + $("#txtDesg").val() + '"}',
```

I guess you have a deserialization issue from Emp**n**ame**s** instead of EmpName defined in your model.

Comment: Hi Didier, I changed Empnames to EmpName and empdesg to EmpDesignation but still I am getting same problem.I removed if else part and return a dummy string.Please suggest

Comment: Hi Didier, I kept try catch inpublic string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo) and received the response body as: {"d":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} Please suggest next step please

Answer (score 0):

After suggestion from Didier I dive deep into my problem and solved.
Here are the changes I have done.

1) In the Iservice1.cs I added URItemplate

[OperationContract]

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", **UriTemplate = "InsertUserDetails"**,

ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);
```

2)In the Html page client side code I modified

```
data: '{"EmpName": "' + $("#txtName").val() + '", "EmpDesignation": "' + $("#txtDesg").val() + '"}'
```

3)In web.config I changed code added `<webHttp />` Instead of `<enableWebScript />` because according to MSDN:

**<webHttp />**
This element specifies the WebHttpBehavior on an endpoint through configuration. This behavior, when used in conjunction with the `<webHttpBinding>` standard binding, enables the Web programming model for a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service.

```
 <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
      <!--<enableWebScript />-->
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Thanks for all of your suggestions.